# Manual transmission lugging in first gear

Tags: manual-transmission

I drive a 2006 Subaru Legacy Wagon with a 5-speed manual transmission. When I've been driving it recently I have had more trouble then I remember starting it on an uphill. When I use the same power that I am used to using, the engine will begin to lug and the car will not move forward. The car is certainly aging.

Is this something that happens to a car over time, or could something else be the problem? Or I am probably the problem (I don't drive it as much as I used to).

Comment: How many miles are on the clutch?  Is the "Check Engine" or "Service Engine Soon" light lit?  Do you use the clutch pedal as a footrest, or  make a habit of holding the clutch in when you will be moving in a minute or two, e.g. at a red light?

Comment: The clutch is less than a year old, there are no lights on. I am not a perfect driver but the previous clutch lasted ~70k miles in the city (and survived 3 people learning how to drive stick on it). I try to not make a habit of holding the clutch for too long.